# how to use terraform with nsd?

Tags: domain-name-system, terraform, openbsd, nsd

is it possible to manage nsd dns with terraform? i keep getting a `NOTINT` error but per man page there is an option to accept `UPDATE` opcodes. when i set `drop-updates: no` nsd starts fine but i get the same error.

given option is in the man page it seems like it should be supported but doesnt seem to be.

https://man.openbsd.org/nsd.conf

is there some other setting i need for the terraform dns provider to work with this?
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/dns/latest

Answer (score 0):

Was just looking into this to use it myself but ran across:

[Hashicorp's DNS provider states](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/dns/latest)

> Supports DNS updates (RFC 2136)...

[while NSD's REQUIREMENTS file reads](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/nsd/blob/master/doc/REQUIREMENTS#L1016)

> RFC2136 (Dynamic update) are not implemented and will not be implemented as
> zone control is not implemented in NSD itself.

so I don't see it happening...